# How do I load official modules with uFlash into the BBC micro:bit?

Tags: micropython, bbc-microbit

I've been coding the BBC micro:bit with the [micro:bit Python Editor](https://python.microbit.org/v/3) with no problems.

Now I'm working with a more modest computer, and would like to code with emacs+[uflash](https://uflash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

My problem is that when I upload the firmware with `uflash`, and try to import the `log` module, I get this error:

```
>>> import log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'log'
```

However, some modules load with no problem, like `import radio` or `import neopixel`.

I don't know what to do; thank you very much in advance!